# IntentService + WakefulBroadcastReceiver + AlarmManager are deprecated with API 26 (Android 8.0 Oreo). Which is the best alternative?

Tags: android, deprecated, intentservice, android-8.0-oreo

Sometimes in my apps I need to do something in the background repeatedly (every X hours).

Up to API 25 i use:

- `AlarmManager` with setInexactRepeating (to respect battery)
- `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to have enough times to do all works
- `IntentService` to do all in background thread

On API 26 all of this are deprecated or limited and are suggested to use `JobScheduler` with `JobService` instead.

The problem is that `JobService` run in main thread.

I think to use `AsyncTask` inside `JobService` and call `JobService.jobFinished` inside `onPostExecute`

this is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use JobIntentService of support library 26 which has the exact workflow of IntentService. For pre Oreo devices, JobIntentService will use old IntentService. JobIntentService class relies on JobScheduler API of android.

For more,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html

Comment: JobIntentService has the exact workflow of IntentService+WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: It is not exactly the same. JobIntentService is not guaranteed to start working immedeately. It can take a lot of time for the Job to be actually executed.

Answer (score 6):

> On API 26 all of this are deprecated or limited

`AlarmManager` did not change in Android 8.0, IIRC. `IntentService` did not change in Android 8.0 either. However, you would need to make the `IntentService` be a foreground service and use a `getForegroundService()` `PendingIntent`.

> The problem is that JobIntentService run in main thread.

`onHandleWork()` is called on a background thread, both for Android 8.0+ and pre-8.0 devices. I used [this sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Service/JobIntentService), adding logging statements to log the current thread ID inside `enqueueWork()` (called on the main application thread) and `onHandleWork()`. They are different thread IDs, and hence they are different threads.

> this is the correct way to do this?

No, just do your work in `onHandleWork()`.

Comment: from IntentService doc:

"Note: IntentService is subject to all the background execution limits imposed with Android 8.0 (API level 26). In most cases, you are better off using JobIntentService, which uses jobs instead of services when running on Android 8.0 or higher."

also i need to run service each X hours (not exactly) even if app is closed, so i cant run enqueueWork directly

Comment: @Xan: "from IntentService doc" -- which is why I pointed out that you would need to make it a foreground service. "also i need to run service each X hours (not exactly) even if app is closed" -- then use `JobScheduler` directly, forking a regular thread (not an `AsyncTask`) from `onStartJob()`.

Comment: sorry i confused JobIntentService with JobService in question.  so we can use JobIntentService as IntentService and JobService as Service ? can i use JobIntentService inside JobScheduler ? (i will edit question)

Comment: @Xan: You use a `JobService` with `JobScheduler`. You use `JobIntentService` as a replacement for `IntentService` (e.g., with `AlarmManager`, using a `BroadcastReceiver` `PendingIntent`, where the receiver calls `enqueueWork()` on the `JobIntentService`).

Comment: so using AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver and JobIntentService there is no problem with API 26 ? (about background limitation)

Comment: @Xan: It's more that you get ~10 minutes instead of ~1 minute. If you have work that might exceed 10 minutes, use a foreground `IntentService`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156386/discussion-between-xan-and-commonsware).

Comment: @CommonsWare PendingIntent.getForegroundService requires API 26 , is there any why to get this on PRE 26 ? Support library?

Comment: @redochka: On previous versions, you would just use `PendingIntent.getService()`.

Comment: @Xan AlarmManager not depreceted but only "Note: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested."

Comment: @CommonsWare  I used a JobIntentService to fire Notifications to the user when exact Alarms were triggered. What do you suggest I use now that JobIntentService is deprecated?  WorkManager?

Comment: @AJW: That depends on whether there is other work. If all you are doing is just displaying the `Notification`, with no I/O, then a regular short-lived background `Service` or even a `BroadcastReceiver` might suffice -- basically, whatever is directly responding to the `AlarmManager` event. If, however, you need to do disk or network I/O as part of displaying the `Notification`, then `WorkManager` probably is a good idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare an AlarmManager gets triggered when an exact calendar due date is hit, which then runs a BroadcastReceiver to launch the JobIntentService.  And the JobIntentService fires a simple Notification message to the user.  So pretty simple and no network I/O...so would recommend to just use Service?

Comment: @AJW: I would just do it all in the `BroadcastReceiver`. Raising a `Notification` should be very cheap in your case; I do not know what value you got from the `JobIntentService`.

Comment: Ok.  I set up the JobIntentService so the Notification firing and delivery to the user was on a worker thread because I thought BroadcastReceiver is always run on the UI thread.  Are you saying that the Notification firing and delivery is such a small hit to the main thread that it is not necessary to put on a worker thread for background processing?

Comment: @AJW: "Are you saying that the Notification firing and delivery is such a small hit to the main thread that it is not necessary to put on a worker thread for background processing?" -- correct. We need worker threads for I/O or computationally-intensive work. Raising a `Notification` should not qualify for either of those.

Comment: @CommonsWare Very good...you are a gentleman and a scholar.  Cheers.

Comment: CommonsWare I forgot to ask you about this use case:  would resetting say 200 calendar date alarms in a for loop, based on a device reboot event BOOT_COMPLETED be computationally-intensive?  If yes, then have BroadcastReceiver launch WorkManager for execution in a worker thread?

Comment: @AJW: "would resetting say 200 calendar date alarms in a for loop... be computationally-intensive?" -- I am not certain what it means to reset a calendar date alarm. You could use logging to determine how long it takes.